# Unable to remove an item from lsitviewbox

Tags: c#

In C# windows application, I am comparing two different string arrays and depending on which array size is big, I add or delete items to a list view box. using the below code I am able to add to list view without any issues, but I am not able to remove from it.

I get an error that says.

> "Error CS1503, Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem'"

Here is an excerpt from my code

```
        string[] currentFilesList = GetFileList();  
        if (currentFilesList.Length > prevFilesList.Length)
        {
            var addedList = currentFilesList.Except(prevFilesList).ToArray();
            foreach (var item in addedList)
            {
                listView1.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
        if (currentFilesList.Length < prevFilesList.Length)
        {
            var removedList = prevFilesList.Except(currentFilesList).ToArray();
            foreach (string item in removedList)
            {                   
                    listView1.Items.Remove(item);    //I get error here on "item" Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem'"                    
            }
        }
        prevFilesList = currentFilesList;
```

I tried both string and var but same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can remove item by

```
  foreach (string item in removedList)
{
        var toRemove =listView1.Items.Find(item);
        if (toRemove != null)
        {
           listView1.Items.Remove(toRemove);
        }
}
```

or you can use `RemoveByKey`

```
foreach (string item in removedList)
    {

               listView1.Items.RemoveByKey(item);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by using linq

```
var newlist = listView1.Cast<ListViewItem>().Where(p=>p.Text.Contains("OBJECT")).ToList().ForEach(listBox1.Items.Remove);
```